# ggtern not compatible with ggsave or ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I get this error message whenever I try to use a ggtern object with ggplot2:ggsave or with ggarrange. I am trying to combine a ggtern plot with a ggpplot.

```
library(ggtern)


DATA <- data.frame(A = runif(100), B = runif(100), C = runif(100))
plot <- ggtern(data = DATA, 
               mapping = aes(x = A, y = B, z = C)) + 
        geom_point() + ggtern::theme_bw(base_size = 30) + theme_arrowlarge()
plot

ggplot2::ggsave(plot,file=paste0('ternary plot','.png'),width=30,height=25,units='cm',dpi=600)
```

> Error: CoordTern requires the following missing aesthetics (tlr->xy) :
> z

```
ggpubr::ggarrange(plot)
```

> Error: CoordTern requires the following missing aesthetics (tlr->xy) :
> z

Why these error messages and how can this be resolved?

Comment: What is the `output` object you are trying to save? Shouldn't this be the `plot` object?

Comment: @AllanCameron yes sorry! I just corrected it.

Comment: I think ggtern might be overwriting the default ggplot2 print/plot/draw S3 methods that aren't on the search paths of `ggplot2::ggsave()` or `ggpubr::ggarrange`.